# Раздельный счет цифр php

Tags: php

В файл поступают значения "1 0 1 -1 -3 1 1 1 1" и значение "154". Код php считает все цифры:

```
 $file = file_get_contents('test.txt'); 
 preg_match_all("/[^\b\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\b][0-9\.-]+/", $file, $numbers);
 foreach($numbers[0] as $num) {
$sum = $sum + $num; //складываем
}
$data = $sum
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы "154" не считалось вместе с другими цифрами, а было отдельной переменной? Можно заключить число в любые спец. символы и скобки, если это поможет.

Comment: Мне одному кажется, что в регулярном выражении написан бред?

Comment: Если у вас в строке числа через пробел идут, то преобразуйте строку в массив по пробелам, затем элементы массива в цикле преобразовывайте из строк в числа и уже с ними делайте что захотите.

Comment: Я уверен, что эту задачу регулярными выражениями не нужно даже пытаться решить. Задача решается разбиением строки по пробелам и простыми сравнениями.

Comment: опубликуйте файл test.txt

Comment: Пусть test.txt будет = "1 0 1 -1 -3 1 1 1 1 154"

Answer (score 1):

Если содержимое файла = "1 0 1 -1 -3 1 1 1 1 154", то подойдет следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/(?:\b154\b)|(-?\d+)/g
```

Оно ищет `154`, `цифры`, `-цифры`, но `154` не запоминает

Ссылка на пример: https://regex101.com/r/iG1uT2/2